# Finding the index and the value of the uniquely longest strings in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 5x500k pandas dataframe and want to locate outlier indexes where the content is an abnormaly long string of characters.

```
for col in df.columns:
   print(df[col].apply(str).map(len).max()) #finds max length of a string in the column col
   print(df[col].apply(str).map(len))       #Gives length of all strings in the column col
```

What I would like to do is to find the longest string in each column and set it to NaN if there are no other strings with the same length (e.g. not multiple longest strings). And also save the index for this value. I want to repeat this for each column until no column has any "uniquely long" strings.

```
Example input:
                a            b                        c           d     e
0             NaN     54674054               6613722414     2330536     NaN
1             NaN         1234                     asdf     2339933     NaN
2           14242       423124   gsdgsgdfgaadfg sdaasda         NaN     NaN
3          342543       214124                      NaN        1231     978ad6f7d8yv 6767969
4            4123       512353                SDFAGdssd          12     87612378y8q7ssdy
5            4473        32325                as asfsda         NaN     NaN

Should Output:
                a            b                        c           d     e
0             NaN          NaN               6613722414     2330536     NaN
1             NaN         1234                     asdf     2339933     NaN
2             NaN       423124                      NaN         NaN     NaN
3             NaN       214124                      NaN        1231     NaN
4            4123       512353               2SDFAGdssd          12     NaN
5            4473        32325               as  asfsda         NaN     NaN
```

Because I would like to clear my big dataset from long string obvious anomalies. Is it possible to easily do such an operation with pandas?

Maybe a more general version of the question would be, how can I find the index and the value of all the longest strings in a pandas dataframe column? And not just the first occurrence of the longest string.

Thank you very much,

Karl

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it but I think you are looking for something like this:

```py
for col in df.columns:
   # find indices, keep="all" means keep all occurrences. 
   idxs = df[col].astype(str).str.len().nlargest(
       1, keep="all"
   ).index
   # get values.
   values = df.loc[idxs, col]
```